# How to type a Vue.component using typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have an util function that reset all data content of some Vue component.

```
export function resetData(vm: any) {
  Object.assign(vm.$data, vm.$options.data.call(vm));
}
```

And I'm trying to remove the "any" type of my Vue.component, is it possible? There are any Interface that target $data from Vue?

I need to get this type:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `resetData` function require a Vue Instance parameter

In this case imports `Vue` from the `"vue"` package and use it as a type

```
import Vue from "vue";

export function resetData(vm: Vue) { ... }
```

Vue object has `$data` and `$options` parameters as expected.

The remaining problem is to know what the object `$options.data` holds. Once `data` is a not know type but we are using it as a function, in other words: `()=>void`. Or else it will raise a syntax error.

```
Object.assign(vm.$data, (vm.$options.data as ()=>void).call(vm));
```

The final code with no compilations errors will be like

```
import Vue from "vue";
export function resetData(vm: Vue) {
    Object.assign(vm.$data, (vm.$options.data as ()=>void).call(vm));
}
```

The code becomes a little verbose but now is well tight on its own typing